# 'cannot filter palette images' error when doing a ImageEnhance.Sharpness()

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a GIF image file. I opened it using [`PIL.Image`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) and did a couple of size transforms on it. Then I tried to use [`ImageSharpness.Enhance()`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imageenhance.htm#tag-ImageEnhance.Sharpness) on it...

```
sharpener = PIL.ImageEnhance.Sharpness(img)
sharpened = sharpener.enhance(2.0)
```

This is causing an exception:

```
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>
('cannot filter palette images',)
```

I tried to google for this error, but did not find anything. Can someone help me figure out what is going wrong?

FYI the mode of the input image is `'P'`. I don't have this problem if I work with jpg images.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
sharpener = PIL.ImageEnhance.Sharpness (img.convert('RGB'))
```

It's quite common for algorithms to be unable to work with a palette based image. The `convert` in the above changes it to have a full RGB value at each pixel location.

Comment: Thanks! Which image modes should I do this for? Should I do it for everything except 'RGB' and 'RGBA' ?

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your quick answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom can you clarify what you meant wit 'L' mode (is it an image format like 'RGB'?). EDIT found some info [The mode attribute defines the number and names of the bands in the image, and also the pixel type and depth. Common modes are “L” (luminance) for greyscale images, “RGB” for true color images, and “CMYK” for pre-press images.](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/tutorial.html#using-the-image-class)

Comment: @sehe RGB is 3 color channels, RGBA is 4 channels, and L is only 1 channel. Otherwise they're very similar and the same operations should work on them, which is why I made the comment.